# Print only even numbers from an array

Tags: ruby

I'm working my way through a Ruby tutorial. One of the questions provides an array. You then have to:

> "Write a loop that only puts the even values of `my_array`. (Bonus points if you use a one-line `if`!)"

My answer passes the test but shows a syntax error, my answer is the if statement below. Can someone explain why I get the syntax error?

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

if my_array.each do |x| % 2 == 0 puts X
```

Comment: what is the syntax error that you get? Did you try and run it on your own machine? do you still get the same syntax error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing an `end` statement for your `do` and a left operand for your modulus.  Try this:

```
my_array = (1..10).to_a
my_array.each { |x| puts x if x.even? }
```

Answer (score 6):

There is really no need to call `puts` in each iteration. It would be perfectly fine to do:

```
arr = *(1..10)
puts a.select(&:even?)
#=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Or, if you want the result concatenated as a string:

```
arr = *(1..10)
puts a.select(&:even?).join(", ")
#=> 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write code like this

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
my_array.each do |x| 
  if x % 2 == 0 
    puts x 
  end
end
```

1 line version

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].partition(&:even?).first
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to do the if code on one line?

Comment: 1 line version added

Answer (score 0):

Do this stuff on `irb` yourself and go through it line by line.

```
> irb(main):001:0> arr = [1,2,3]
> => [1, 2, 3]
> 
> irb(main):018:0> arr.each { |x| x }
> => [1, 2, 3]
> 
> irb(main):019:0> someVar = arr.each { |x| x }
> => [1, 2, 3]
> 
> irb(main):021:0> someVar % 2
```

As you can see, you're trying to modulo an array which isn't possible. You are doing this in your if statement. `if {lhs} % {rhs}` where left hand side is the array & right hand side is 2. If we simulate this behavior, we get the same output as above

```
irb(main):022:0> if someVar % 2
irb(main):023:1> puts x
irb(main):024:1> end
NoMethodError: undefined method `%' for [1, 2, 3]:Array
    from (irb):22
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```